# How to make position fixed item same width as flex parent

Tags: css, flexbox

I want the fixed progress bar have same width as the yellow container and always positioned at the bottom of screen which overlapping on top of yellow container with CSS.

I have try to using `width: inherit` in the fixed child but the yellow parent do not have width so it doesn't work.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 1200px;
}

.left {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
}

.right {
  flex: 1;
  background: yellow;
}

.progress {
  position: fixed;
  background: gray;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">

  </div>
  <div class="right">

      <div class="progress">I'm progress bar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the container width is 500px, you are using flex:1 so the width should be 250px

Comment: @TemaniAfif Can we get container width using CSS? what if the container width will change? Or if we don't know which is the container of the fixed item?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Position fixed will be fixed to the page's scroll position and should not be used as a child of a static element.

Instead, you should set position to `absolute` on the progress bar, and position `relative` on the container.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}

.left {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
}

.right {
  flex: 1;
  background: yellow;
}

.progress {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <div class="progress">I'm progress bar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use JavaScript to match two elements width's while keeping position `fixed` using `offsetWidth`.

```js
function resizeProgress() {
  const container = document.querySelector('.container');
  const progress = document.querySelector('.progress');
      
  progress.style.width = container.offsetWidth + 'px';
  progress.style.left = container.offsetLeft + 'px';
}
```

```js
function resizeProgress() {
  const container = document.querySelector('.container');
  const progress = document.querySelector('.progress');
  
  progress.style.width = container.offsetWidth + 'px';
  progress.style.left = container.offsetLeft + 'px';
}

resizeProgress();
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 1200px;
}

.left {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
}

.right {
  flex: 1;
  background: yellow;
}

.progress {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
  </div>

  <div class="right">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="progress">I'm progress bar</div>
```

Comment: My purpose is to scroll the page and keep the progress bar fixed position on screen when scrolling, so using position absolute will not work.

Comment: @Eason so the flex parent will not be fixed, and will be static on the page but the progress bar will be fixed and scroll with the page?

Comment: yes, correct. Only the progress bar need to fixed and scroll, the yellow and blue container will have a big height and static on page.

Comment: @Eason I have added JavaScript to match the widths.

Comment: As I'm using React so I don't want to using javascript to adjust it.

Comment: There is no other way I'm afraid. You'll have to `useRef` and `useEffect` to get the job done.